# Select2: tagging using an array from remote data?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, jquery-select2

I'm starting with Select2. I want to combine "Tagging Support" and "Loading remote data" (see http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

In the body of an HTML file, I presently have an input form:

```
<input id="topics">
```

with "Tagging Support" using a list of tags given by an array, as the following script of the head of the HTML file shows:

```
$("#topics").select2({
     placeholder: "Choose topic(s)",    
     tags:["russia", "europe", "obama"]
});
```

I also have a server, made in Node.js using Express, that is connected to a database. I know how to handle requests (POST or GET) on the server side, in connection with the database.

For the input form of my HTML file, I want, instead of the array ["russia", "europe", "obama"], to use an array of data provided by the server.

How could I write it?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is https://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#data

Comment: In fact I don't know how to start, because the examples that I can see on getting remote data seems to get a "data.json" file, which is not my case because what my server has to send, from a GET request, is an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Backend**

You'll have to create a short route like this:

```
app.get('/foo/bar.json', function(req, res){
     //...
     res.send(data);
}
```

**Frontend**

```
$("#topics").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for a movie",
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
        url: "/foo/bar.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        results: function (data, page) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter remote JSON data
            return {results: data};
        }
    },
});
```

And a JSON object can be/contain arrays. See https://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#data

Comment: Thanks! Backend seems to work this way (I guess I was a bit stupid regarding the server-side). But frontend is showing "searching" in the "topics" input...

Comment: To be more precise, the JSON sent by the server is just an array of strings, like that: `[
  "obama",
  "ukraine",
  "russia"
]`. How to code the frontend to make this array be the list of tags available for the field?

Comment: @GBC yes, but also consider logging input and output values

Comment: I have looked at other questions on Stack Over Flow. Select2 seems to need `id` and `text` in the array to use it in the form. I tried (following [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160225/select2-text-is-undefined-when-getting-json-using-ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160225/select2-text-is-undefined-when-getting-json-using-ajax)): `results: function (data, page) { var newData = []; _.each(data, function (item) { newData.push({ id: item.Id, text: item.DisplayString }); }); return { results: newData }; } ` but it's not working.

Comment: It might be because _.each is async. Try a for loop perhaps.

Comment: Thanks! With a loop: `results: function (data, page) { var newData = []; for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { newData[i] = { id: data[i], text: data[i] } } return { results: newData }; }` I can get newData which is the following array `[ { id: 'obama', text: 'obama' }, { id: 'ukraine', text: 'ukraine' }, { id: 'russia', text: 'russia' } ]` which is a good step, I guess...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your comments. I cannot get how `formatSelection` and `formatInput` should work but it's a complementary question, so I posted it [separately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643409/in-select2-how-do-formatselection-and-formatresult-work).