# In Select2, how do formatSelection and formatResult work?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) to have an input field of a form (let's say its id is `topics`) to be in tagging mode, with the list of existing tags (allowing the user to choose some of these tags, or to create new ones) being provided by an array of remote data.

The array (`list.json`) is correctly got from my server. It has `id` and `text` fields, since Select2 seems to need these fields. It thus looks like this:

```
[ { id: 'tag1', text: 'tag1' }, { id: 'tag2', text: 'tag2' }, { id: 'tag3', text: 'tag3' } ]
```

The script in the HTML file looks like this:

```
$("#topics").select2({
    ajax: { 
        url: "/mypath/list.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        results: function (data, page) { 
        return {results: data};
        },   
    }
});
```

But the input field is showing "searching", which means it's not able to use the array for tagging support.

In the script with Select2, I know I have to define `formatSelection` and `formatInput`, but I'm not getting how they should work in my case, although I have read the Select2 documentation... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the function like explained [here](https://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#templating). In your example:

```
function format(state) {

    return state.text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this: `function format(item) { return item.text; }
    $("#topics").select2({
        ajax: { 
        url: "/mypath/list.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        results: function (data, page) { 
            return {results: data};
            }
        },  
        formatResult: format,
        formatSelection: format,
        escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
    });` but it's still not working.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing? undefined? I not called at all?

Comment: Can you log the data after the Ajax?

Comment: I could log `data` on the server-side, but could log nothing on the client-side .But I found the problem (message in the console on the client-side): my server was not allowing Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), and since I was doing tests from a separate HTML file, it could not work. I fixed that. It is now working. Thank you very much for your help and your patience!

Comment: In Select2 4.* the "formatters" have been renamed to **templateSelection** and **templateResult** and their signatures have changed as well. Please refer to https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html