# Select2 Not Showing the Results of Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

i am trying to implement Remote Data Select2.

Json Data is coming Fine, but select2 don't show the results instead it shows only spinner image and says loading.

Here is **Json**

```
[{"FormID":"1","FormName":"Dashboard"}]
```

I only want FormName to be shown in the results but it is not working :(

**Script**

```
    $('#selectParentMenu').select2({
       minimumInputLength:2,
       placeholder:"Select Parent Menu",
        ajax: {
            type:"post",
            url: "{{base_url()}}admin/configurations/loadAllParentFormNames/",
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 100,
            data: function(term, page) {
                return {
                    types: ["exercise"],
                    limit: -1,
                    term: term
                };
            },
            results: function(data, page ) {
                return { results: data.FormName }
            }
        },
        formatResult: function(exercise) {
            return "<div class='select2-user-result'>" + exercise.term + "</div>";
        },
        formatSelection: function(exercise) {
            return exercise.term;
        },
        initSelection : function (element, callback) {
            var elementText = $(element).attr('data-init-text');
            callback({"term":elementText});
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="col-lg-8" id="haveParentDiv">
    <input class="make-switch" id="haveParent" type="checkbox" data-on-color="success" data-on-text="Yes" data-off-text="NO" data-off-color="danger">
     </div>
```

[image]

i think the Problem is with

```
        results: function(data, page ) {
            return { results: data.FormName }
        }
```

but i am not sure what to write with data.??

when i tried only data, then instead of searching it said undefined, but at least i knew it can give result and something is wrong here.

I am following this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/LUsMb/16/

Comment: Does ajax even provide `results` property?

Comment: @hjpotter92
well select2 in tutorial itself added the result and it works for them. http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#ajax

Comment: Had a similar problem. Was using v4 that replaced `results` with `processResults`. Everything worked fine after renaming the function.

Answer (score 0):

i had to do little changes in my code, but its working now.

Script:

```
$('#selectParentMenu').select2({
               minimumInputLength:1,
               placeholder:"Select Parent Menu",
                ajax: {
                    type:"post",
                    url: "{{base_url()}}admin/configurations/loadAllParentFormNames/",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    quietMillis: 100,
                    data: function(term, page) {
                        return {
                            term: term, //search term
                            page_limit: 10 // page size
                        };
                    },
                    results: function(data, page ) {
                        var newData = [];
                        _.each(data, function (item) {
                            newData.push({
                                id: item.FormID  //id part present in data
                                , text: item.FormName  //string to be displayed
                            });
                        });
                        return { results: newData };
                    }

                }
            });
```

I removed some old lines which i mostly didnt understood. and added this..

```
results: function(data, page ) {
    var newData = [];
    _.each(data, function (item) {
        newData.push({
            id: item.FormID  //id part present in data
            , text: item.FormName  //string to be displayed
        });
    });
    return { results: newData };
}
```

i got this code from

> [select2: "text is undefined" when getting json using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160225/select2-text-is-undefined-when-getting-json-using-ajax)

Well there is some issue, i had to use underscore.js library, if anyone can change little peice of code to normal for loop i will love accept his/answer. i don't want extra library with my code.

Please change this to normal for loop if anyone can.

```
_.each(data, function (item) {
                            newData.push({
                                id: item.FormID  //id part present in data
                                , text: item.FormName  //string to be displayed
                            });
```

---

update:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
                            newData.push({
                                id: data[i].FormID,  //id part present in data
                                text: data[i].FormName  //string to be displayed
                            });
```

Thanks to stackoverflow community, helped me solved the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `result: function(data, page)` by `processResults: function(data, page)`